# Formula to hide rows based on the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that contains the names of all managers and their employees, ideally the way this sheet needs to work is that there is a drop down in the top left and when a manager selects their name, all rows that don't have their name against, are hidden, so only their team is shown.

I know auto filtering and having them choose their name would be the easiest way and is a good option to fall back on, but I'm hoping there is a way to do this with VBA or a formula to just hide rows when its not their team when they select their name in the drop down. As i'm trying to create something that's quite slick and looks nice

I did try to do something around having a helper cell to display true and false if the names matched, but came a bit stuck at this point. Tried using the code below, but it doesn't seem to actually be doing anything. Column with TRUE/FALSE is in Col A

```
Sub TEST()
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell In Range("A4:A34")
If cell.Value = "FALSE" Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to do this without just using autofilter would be great

Comment: Autofilter is the obvious solution here...  If you really want to use VBA then try writing some code and post back if you run into a *specific" problem.

Comment: Please read the FAQ to learn how this site works and how to ask a question. You don't show any attempt at a solution. This is not a script order service.

Comment: SO is Q&A not an Excel trivia site. Read [ask] and spare a moment for the [tour].

Comment: FWIW no formula could ever hide a row. Formulas are functions that take input and produce output, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: The idea behind the formula was to return True/False to display if the name matched, then in the VBA do something like Sub TEST()

    `Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In Range("A4:A34")
    If cell.Value = "FALSE" Then
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True`  
My apologies for not asking the question in the correct way

Comment: If you have written some code and ran into a *specific* issue, by all means [edit] your question to add that code in and *ask about that specific issue*. Right now your question looks more like "I need XYZ, can someone do it for me?" - which isn't going to end well.

Comment: Code added, Wasn't my intention to come across as "I want this, give it to me" at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following assumptions:

- Drop down with Manager name is in cell A1
- Column listing manager name for each row is in column A
- Data set starts in row 5
- Column A is contiguous with no blank spaces

Place the following code into the `Worksheet` module of the data sheet and change assumptions to fit your data set.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" and Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Range("A5:A1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Dim mgrList as Range
        Set mgrList = Range(Range("A5"),Range("A5").End(xlDown))

        Dim mgrCheck as Range
        For each mgrCheck in mgrList
            mgrCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = mgrCheck <> Target
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott - Thanks for the reply, I've put it into the worksheet module and moved my data around to match the requirements of your code to test it, i seem to be getting a "Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name" when changing the drop down box and can't figure out why

Comment: @AshleyThomson - Sorry. See my edit. I forgot `ByVal` in argument of procedure name.

Comment: Sorry just though of something - is there any easy way to make it unhide when you re-select one that has already been hidden. So if i choose manager 1 it will hide 2 and 3, but If I then want to choose Manager 2 is there anyway unhide it and hide 1 and 3. Is there anyway to amend this code to include this? @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @AshleyThomson - it should do that each time. It should only show the mgr you choose and nothing else.

Comment: It does do that perfectly, but when i go to choose one that has been hidden previously, it then won't show it, it remains hidden and nothing is shown on the sheet

Comment: Yes. I see that now @AshleyThomson. My assumption was wrong. See my edit. It will work for you as needed now.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thank you so much for the help @ScottHoltzman

Answer (score 0):

Use an if then else statement with a call that shows/hides the rows that you'd like to show.

```
If Range("A1").Value = "John Snow" Then
Call Show_John_Snow
Else
If Range("A1").Value = "Daenerys Targaryen" Then
Call Show_Daenerys
Else....
```

'subroutine

```
Show_John_Snow
Rows("17:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide others
Rows("21:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False 'show John Snow
Rows("54:75").EntireRow.Hidden = True  'hide others
```

Comment: Sorry to be *that guy*, but answering blatantly off-topic questions is generally frowned upon.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Read the comments under the question: this isn't the type of questions that belongs on this site. Read [ask] and see [help/on-topic] and [mcve] and half of [meta] if you're not sure what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I have this data, in which I have Headers at A3:D3, data starting from row 4 to 99.
I tried applying Autofilter, check if this one works for you.

```
Sub test()

    Range("A3:D3").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3:D99").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="0"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3:D99").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
End Sub
```

Here, I selected option named "0" from drop-down filter from Field-2, that is Range A4, and as you told, other cells automatically gets hidden, and the cells corresponding to that criteria only gets visible.
Also I tried with other option "1".

Comment: If there is less data, then try adding lines like the last two for nRows...

Answer (score 0):

This seems a very difficult or involved way to do this, I have to show students their results without them seeing other students results.

So, one sheet has all the data and on a "front" sheet I call the relevant data for the particular student using index() and match(). Each student has an ID number which is entered, then for confirmation the name is returned then the relevant grades.